# Calculate work by a field using Stokes' theorem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let a circle be defined as D={$y^2+z^2=1, x=1$}

Let **u** = $(xyz, xy^2z^3-z,xy^3z^2)$

Calculate the work of the field one lap around the circle.

Stoke's theorem here:
$\int_D \mathbf u $ d**r** = $\int\int_E$(rot **u**)$\cdot$**N** dS

**N** = (1, 0, 0)

(rot **u**)$\cdot$**N** = $\frac{\partial u_3}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial z} = 3xy^2z^2 - (3xy^2z^2 - 1) = 1$

so
$\int\int_E1 dS$ where E is the unit circle gives me $2\pi$

But it should be $\pi$

So it's something silly but I don't know what, any hints?

**Solved**

I used the wrong formula for the area * blush *
A=$\pi r^2$

Comment: By the way, you've ignored orientation issues. Which way are you going around the circle?

Comment: Face origin (standing at a positive x-coordinate) and do one counter clockwise rotation.

Comment: OK, so $(1,0,0)$ is the correct orientation for the outward normal. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The area of a circle with unit radius is $\pi$ not $2\pi$.

Comment: That's not a hint. That's the answer! :P

Comment: Lol thanks... I just got messed up in my head

Comment: @DecafSux  You're welcome!